# How to capture the output of openssl in python

Tags: python, openssl

I am trying to run the following openssl command in python:

```
cmd = "openssl x509 -sha1 -in esx.crt -noout -fingerprint"
tmp = os.popen(cmd)
tmp_sha1 = tmp.readline()
```

This command is supposed to generate a fingerprint of the certificate. I am trying to capture the output through the file object. But when I read this file object, there's nothing in it. I have executed this command on the command line and it runs fine, generates the fingerprint. Could you tell me how can I get the fingerprint?

Comment: Did you mean to type cmd = "openssl x509 -sha1 -in esx.crt -noout -fingerprint"?

Comment: Is it a working directory difference? If you put the full path to `/home/wherever/esx.crt` does that make it work? Maybe openssl is erroring with a file not found error, and you aren't getting stderr to find out.

Comment: @Charanjit: what do you mean by file object, as in writing to a file?

Comment: No, the tmp variable is file object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this natively within Python using the `OpenSSL` module.

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate, FILETYPE_PEM

cert_file_string = open("esx.crt", "rb").read()
cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, cert_file_string)

sha1_fingerprint = cert.digest("sha1")
print sha1_fingerprint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two modules to establish what you want: `subprocess` and `os`.

Using `subprocess` you can check for the output for the process using `communicate()`, which [reads data from stdout and stderr until EOF](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("openssl x509 -sha1 -in 17.cert -noout -fingerprint", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, _ = p.communicate() #return a tuple (stdout, stderr)
>>> out
b'SHA1 Fingerprint=87:68:8B:B0:6A:E2:DF:A3:E2:63:76:97:A9:2B:B4:F4:82:4E:0B:D1\n'
```

Using `os` module works fine as well, using both `read()` and `readline()` methods: (please note that [os.popen() is deprecated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0361/))

```
>>> import os
>>> p = os.popen("openssl x509 -sha1 -in 17.cert -noout -fingerprint")
>>> p.read()
'SHA1 Fingerprint=87:68:8B:B0:6A:E2:DF:A3:E2:63:76:97:A9:2B:B4:F4:82:4E:0B:D1\n'
>>> p = os.popen("openssl x509 -sha1 -in 17.cert -noout -fingerprint")
>>> out = p.readline()
'SHA1 Fingerprint=87:68:8B:B0:6A:E2:DF:A3:E2:63:76:97:A9:2B:B4:F4:82:4E:0B:D1\n'
```

If you want to write the value to a file, that works as well, which you can verify by opening a file `output.txt` in your current working directory:

```
>>> with open('./output.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write(out)
...
77
```

The `77` notifies us that 77 bytes were written to the file, which you can verify by opening it in your favourite text editor.

Comment: So the problem is that it can't find the cert file. It's in the same directory as my python file. This is the command:                          subprocess.Popen("openssl x509 -sha1 -in ./rui.crt -noout -fingerprint")          Error: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Charanjit: I had the 17.cert in the same directory as `openssl` binary, remove the `./` before `rui.crt` and try again :)

Comment: Did that, but it doesn't work. It's a windows system.

Answer (score 0):

```
To capture the result you can use below code 

private_key = subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "genrsa", "4096"],
    check=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).stdout

to generate public key use below code 

pubkey = subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "rsa", "-pubout"],
    input=private_key,
    check=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).stdout
```

Resource : https://www.zimuel.it/blog/sign-and-verify-a-file-using-openssl